# Парсинг строки на c#

Tags: c#, синтаксический-анализ

Есть строка вида `"key"="value";"key1"="value1";"key2"="value2"`.

У нас имеется строка `key`, нужно найти, что содержится после первого `"="` и до `";"`.

То есть, зная ключ, нужно отпарсить его значение.

Comment: Регулярные выражения, не?

Comment: Регулярка тут лишняя имхо, ваш вариант со сплитом более удобен и прост. Хотя, конечно, зависит от размера строки.

Comment: Если значения могут содержать символ `=`, то простым `String.Split()` не обойтись.

Comment: Почему? Split("\";\"").Split("\"=\"") :-)

Comment: key.Split(";")[0].Split("=")[1]; ?

Answer (score 8):

Как-то так должно пойти:

```
var s = "\"key\"=\"value\";\"key1\"=\"value1\";\"key2\"=\"value2\"";
var dict = s.Split(';')
            .Select(part => part.Split('=')
                                .Select(token => token.Trim('"')))
            .ToDictionary(tokens => tokens.First(),
                          tokens => tokens.Skip(1).Single());
var res = dict["key"];
```

---

Если ваши ключи или значения могут содержать знаки равенства или игнорируемые пробелы, так просто распарсить не выйдет, придётся написать хотя бы токенизатор. Например, такой код справляется с более враждебным вводом:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var s = "\"key\"=\"value\";\"key=1\"=\"value=1\" ;" +
                " \"   key2\" =\"va\\\\\\\"lue2\"";
        var dict = new SimpleTokenizer(s)
                        .GetTokens()
                        .SplitByToken(";")
                        .Select(ParseTerm)
                        .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
        var res = dict["key"];
    }

    static KeyValuePair<string, string> ParseTerm(IEnumerable<string> term)
    {
        using (var it = term.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (!it.MoveNext()) // no first token => error
                throw new ArgumentException("term format wrong");
            var key = it.Current; // key is first token
            if (!it.MoveNext() || it.Current != "=") // second token must be "="
                throw new ArgumentException("term format wrong");
            if (!it.MoveNext()) // no third token => error
                throw new ArgumentException("term format wrong");
            var value = it.Current; // value is third token
            if (it.MoveNext()) // trailing tokens => error
                throw new ArgumentException("term format wrong");
            return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, value);
        }
    }
}

class SimpleTokenizer
{
    string source;
    public SimpleTokenizer(string source) { this.source = source; }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetTokens()
    {
        StringBuilder quotedString = null;
        bool escapeMode = false;
        foreach (var c in source)
        {
            if (quotedString == null)
            {
                if (char.IsWhiteSpace(c)) // ignoring whitespace in normal mode
                    continue;
                if (c == '"') // starting quote mode
                    quotedString = new StringBuilder();
                else
                    yield return c.ToString();
            }
            else if (escapeMode)
            {
                if (c == '\\' || c == '"')
                    quotedString.Append(c);
                else
                    throw new ArgumentException("invalid escape: \\" + c);
                escapeMode = false;
            }
            else // pure quote mode
            {
                if (c == '"') // leaving quote mode
                {
                    yield return quotedString.ToString();
                    quotedString = null;
                }
                else if (c == '\\')
                {
                    escapeMode = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    quotedString.Append(c);
                }
            }
        }
        if (escapeMode)
            throw new ArgumentException(
                "unexpected input stream end after escape character");
        if (quotedString != null)
            throw new ArgumentException(
                "unexpected input stream end in quoted string");
    }
}

static class TokenUtils
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> SplitByToken(
        this IEnumerable<string> list, string token)
    {
        List<string> currentPart = new List<string>();
        foreach (var t in list)
        {
            if (t == token)
            {
                yield return currentPart;
                currentPart = new List<string>();
            }
            else
            {
                currentPart.Add(t);
            }
        }
        yield return currentPart;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

String.Split - метод (Char[])

http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Я просто давно шарп не практиковал, забыл уже, что к чему :)